# RegEx - character not before match

Tags: javascript, regex

I understand the concepts of RegEx, but this is more or less the first time I've actually been trying to write some myself.

As a part of a project, I'm attempting to parse out strings which match to a certain domain (actually an array of domains, but let's keep it simple).

At first I started out with this:

```
url.match('www.example.com')
```

But I noticed I was also getting input like this:

> http://www.someothersite.com/page?ref=http://www.example.com

These rows will of course match for `www.example.com` but I wish to exclude them. So I was thinking along these lines: Only match rows that contain `www.example.com`, but not after a `?` character. This is what I came up with:

```
var reg = new RegExp("[^\\?]*" + url + "(\\.*)", "gi");
```

This does however not seem to work, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I fear I've used what little knowledge I yet possess in the matter.

Edit:
Some clarifications.

- The input is logged GET requests. From these I wish to filter out only a few domains. These will have/should handle 0-1 arbitrary subdomains (`example.com`, `www.example.org`, `www.somethirdsite.com` and `web.example.net` should all be valid), these will be stored in a variable.
- I specifically found a request as mentioned above, but I would like to also be able to handle `http://www.someothersite.com/page?ref=https://www.example.com` and `http://www.someothersite.com/page?ref=www.example.com` i.e., if my needle is not part of the request domain, but part of the request data, I do not want the match.

Comment: Danneth, don't get too bogged down with regular expressions, write some tests for the inputs you want to accept and reject, and if a regex satisfies these tests then use it.  Otherwise you can waste alot of time on what is essentially a trivial matter.

Comment: Also, upvote answers which are helpful, and accept the answer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  here is the modified regex for arbitrary domain:

```
RegExp("(^|\\s)(https?://)?(\\w+\\.)?" + url, "gi");
```

The idea here is that you're matching only url preceded by some white spaces character, which makes it impossible to be inside the query.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking, but isn't this the same as my first example? not sure how "/https?:" would function though. Also, I forgot to mention, but there is no guarantee that there will be a "www" part, which means I need some kind of wildcard, which in turn might eat the "?"

Comment: @danneth: what is confusing you about `https?`?

Comment: I actually didn't know what the ? character ment in a regex, told you I was new at this :)  Now I see that Wikipedia has it defined as "Matches the preceding pattern element zero or one times." That makes your example fit better. Although (not specified above) I'm not sure that the second part always will contain another http (but it probably will).

Comment: @danneth: you need to provide exhausting list of possible inputs. It's no good guessing it like this. You've accepted answer that is not satisfying any of your new requirements.

Comment: I have removed the accept and updated the original question, I am not only new to regex but also to this forum, so thank you for your patience